# Drupal6 : Dev - Stage -Online for a small group of developers

Tags: php, drupal, production, stage

I hire tommrow a new developer, since now i worked alone, now i need to do some enviorment to developing and do a stage - online step
what is the leading tools (even if need to pay somthing) to do that?
 i saw webenabled.. so far..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options for this, there is [deployment module](http://drupal.org/project/deploy) that is alpha but apparently works good. Then there is plain old svn ( or even rsync ). That get the job done pretty fast, and give you the added bonus of source code management but you need to transfer databases manually.

Last but not least, and the most powerful method of the 3 mentionned, is [drush](http://drupal.org/node/670460).

Whatever you chose depends on the time you are willing to invest in this step, because short-term they all involve a little more time than just copying a site in another folder but the task would be automated once you do it, so long-term you can easily repeat the deployment and ***this*** is where these tools will make you save time.

Good-luck!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a some sort of [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) (VCS) for your project code. Since Drupal.org now use [Git](http://git-scm.com/) which is pretty good and awesome, you should too. There are several hosting solution for Git, the most popular seems to be [GitHub](https://github.com/).

In your code repository, I recommend not to put the whole site directory but only your own custom code. Regardless the used VCS, here is what I put in my code repository

- A [`.make`](http://drupal.org/project/drush_make) file used to download Drupal core, contrib modules and contrib themes and apply patches (if required)
- a `module` folder with only the custom modules
- a `themes` folder with only the custom themes
- A build script to

  - run `drush make` on the `.make` file to download Drupal core and contribs to a (VCS ignored) `dist` folder
  - copy the `modules` folder to `dist/sites/all/modules/custom`
  - copy the `themes` folder to to `dist/sites/all/themes/custom`

This to

- properly track changes to your project custom code
- properly track used core and contribs versions (in the `.make` file)
- [prevent core or contribs hack](http://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core) but allow patching when required (Drush Make requires the applied patches to be available at a publicly accessible HTTP address)

For the build script, I use [Phing](http://www.phing.info/) but any scripting languages (ant, bash, php, ruby, etc.) could be used. With some additional work, the build script can also be used to run automated test ([SimpleTest](http://drupal.org/simpletest)) and code validation (`php -l` and [Coder Review](http://drupal.org/project/coder)). In the end, the build script produce and update `dist` folder ready for deployment.

For multi developpers project, I try to have as much configurations as possible exported into code instead of working at the database level to store. Mainly by using *exportables* through the [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module and by having a project specific profile to define and update non-exportable configurations through its [`hook_install`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_install/7) and [`hook_update_N`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7) implementations. See [The Development -> Staging -> Production Workflow Problem in Drupal](http://developmentseed.org/blog/2009/jul/09/development-staging-production-workflow-problem-drupal) and the [Code driven development: using Features effectively in Drupal 6 and 7](http://www.archive.org/details/CodeDrivenDevelopmentUsingFeaturesEffectivelyInDrupal6And7) presentation.